# bidirectional text, converting from unicode to ascii on python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, bidirectional

I am trying to write a feature involving translating multilingual text, with bidirectional problems (i.e English words within a Hebrew sentence)

When ordering the text in the right way (after translating), we need to convert it to ascii (regular python str), to use the push notification services of apple and google.

The problem is when converting from unicode to ascii, the string is unordered (the words themselves, not the internal chars order inside the words).

is there a way making sure, that the conversion (unicode -> ascii) will result the proper word ordering?

for instance

```
str1 ='Group1 \xd7\x94\xd7\xa6\xd7\x98\xd7\xa8\xd7\xa3 \xd7\x9c zlatan'
str2 =' \xd7\xa9\xd7\x9c\xd7\x97 \xd7\x94\xd7\x95\xd7\x93\xd7\xa2\xd7\x94'

print str1
print str2
print str2 + '.' + str1
```

the console output will be:

Group1 הצטרף ל zlatan 
שלח הודעה 
.zlatan הצטרף ל Group1 .שלח הודעה

as you can see the words 'Group1' and 'zlatan' got switched, as well as the sentences order

cheers,

Comment: What do you mean by ordering? Could you add the related code snippet?

Comment: Looks fine to me. The first line is rendered in left-to-right order which is appropriate for what appears to be an English sentence with a Hebrew word in it; the last line is rendered in right-to-left order which is appropriate for what appears to be a Hebrew sentence with English words in it. The spacing is funny though, did you not mean `str1 + str2` rather than the other way around? In any case, whatever bidi rendering happens in your console this will not affect the web service you are sending the data to.

Comment: Note that `str1` and `str2` *are* “regular” python 2 strings and that they don't contain text, they contain the *bytes* you get after encoding text as UTF-8. Note also that ASCII character set doesn't contain Hebrew characters. It's quite hard to tell what you expect to happen.